# How do I set an HTML5 offline fallback for my homepage when it's just `/`?

Tags: html, offline-caching, cache-manifest, application-cache

As a modern database-driven website, our homepage is simply `/` instead of `/index.html`. But when I try to set up an offline fallback for just our homepage, it (as the spec intended) sets the fallback for every resource on the site. Is there a way to prevent this aside from changing the path of home?

Comment: Hello Potch! Nice to see you here :)

Comment: What happens when you add the offline fallback to `/index.html` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "problem". After 3 hours of fiddling around I came to my personal conclusion, that application cache does not work in a predictive way using just "/".